# Dynamically appending an array in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I want to append an array with a number depending on the condition of various variables. Here is the code I've come up with: I begin with an empty array.

```
Sub makeArr()
Dim myArr() As Integer
If box1 = True Then
    ReDim Preserve myArr(LBound(myArr) To UBound(myArr) + 1)
    myArr(UBound(myArr)) = 1
End If

If box2 = True Then
    ReDim Preserve myArr(LBound(myArr) To UBound(myArr) + 1)
    myArr(UBound(myArr)) = 2
End If
End Sub
```

Obviously this is an example so not the most elegant way of putting it but it doesn't work as I can't seem to reDim the array as it doesn't initially have a `ubound` or an `lbound`. When I dim it as `myArr(0 to 0)` this also fails.

Any ideas?

Comment: Another approach to testing lbound is to write a little SafeLBound function.  It simply looks at the lbound of the array passed to it, but traps any errors.  If no error, it returns the lbound, if error, it returns 0 or -1 or whatever makes sense as an impossible lbound in your context

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before using the `myArr` array the first time, run this:

```
ReDim Preserve myArr(0 To 1)
```

Then when you come to the dynamic `ReDim` statement, only use `ReDim` if certain conditions are met, e.g. `If UBound(myArr) > 1 then` etc.

```
If box1 = True Then
    If UBound(myArr) > 1 Then
        ReDim Preserve myArr(LBound(myArr) To UBound(myArr) + 1)
    End If
    myArr(UBound(myArr)) = 1
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Olle's solution can be expanded upon with some more checks and balances, if it interests you.

see the `InsertElementIntoArray` Function here:
http://www.cpearson.com/excel/VBAArrays.htm